# FtpWebRequest ServerCertificateValidationCallback never invoked

Tags: vb.net, ssl, ftpwebrequest, servicepointmanager

Win 7, VS2013, .NET 4.5, winforms app

I'm trying to connect to FTP server over SSL/TLS using vb.net. I'm having issues with validating server certificate as ServerCertificateValidationCallback method I'm using seems to be ignored and hence connection to the server never happens, getting a time out error at GetResponse line. I've checked the connection on FileZilla and it works, after adding the server certificate as trusted.

Below's my FtpWebRequest:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(obj as [object], _
cert as X509Certificate, chain as X509Chain, error as SslPolicyErrors) _
(cert.Issuer.Equals("xxxxxx"))

Dim req As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(New Uri("ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx:990")), _
System.Net.FtpWebRequest)

req.EnableSsl = True
req.Credentials = New Net.Credential("user","passw")
req.UsePassive = True
req.UseBinary = True
req.Proxy = Nothing
req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails

Dim res As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(req.GetResponse(),System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
```

I've seen similar topics considering HttpWebRequests, however nothing seems to be usable here. I also enabled tracing to see what's going on in detail:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [17056] Current OS installation type is 'Client'. 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [17056] WebRequest::Create(ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx:990/)
System.Net Information: 0 : [17056] 
FtpWebRequest#::.ctor(ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx:990/)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [17056] Exiting WebRequest::Create()    -> 
FtpWebRequest#
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [17056] 
ServicePoint#::ServicePoint(xxx.xxx.xxx:990)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [17056] FtpWebRequest#::GetResponse()
System.Net Information: 0 : [17056] 
FtpWebRequest#::GetResponse(Method=LIST.)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [17056] 
Socket#::Socket(AddressFamily#2)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [17056] Exiting Socket#::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [17056] 
Socket#::Socket(AddressFamily#23)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [17056] Exiting Socket#6::Socket() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [17056] DNS::TryInternalResolve(xxx.xxx.xxx)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [17056] 
Socket#::Connect(xxx.xxx.xxx:990#-1234)
System.Net.Sockets Information: 0 : [17056] Socket# - Created 
connection from xxx to xxx.xxx.xxx:990.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [17056] Exiting Socket#::Connect() 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [17056] Socket#::Close()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [17056] Socket#::Dispose()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [17056] Exiting Socket#::Close() 
System.Net Information: 0 : [17056] FtpControlStream# - Created 
connection from xxx to xxx.xxx.xxx:990.
System.Net Information: 0 : [17056] Associating FtpWebRequest# with 
FtpControlStream#
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [17056] Socket#::Receive()
The thread 0x4ff0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
System.Net Information: 0 : [0920] ServicePoint# - Closed as idle.
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [17056] 
Socket#::UpdateStatusAfterSocketError() - TimedOut
System.Net.Sockets Error: 0 : [17056] Exception in Socket#::Receive 
- A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly 
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because 
connected host has failed to respond.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [17056] Exiting Socket#::Receive()  
-> Int32#0
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [17056] Socket#::Dispose()
System.Net Information: 0 : [17056] FtpWebRequest#::(Releasing FTP 
connection#)
System.Net Error: 0 : [17056] Exception in 
FtpWebRequest#::GetResponse - The operation has timed out..
at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in 
System.dll
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [17056] Exiting 
FtpWebRequest#::GetResponse()
```

I see that there's an association lacking between FtpWebRequest and service point. Does anyone know how to fix it? I'd appreciate some directions or code samples.

Comment: What protocol is this Ftp server using? If it's Tls 1.2 (probable), you don't have it enabled from what I see here. Your callback setup is also not correct.

Comment: @Jimi Actually the protocol is Tls 1.0, so I'd thought it should have worked. About the callback, would something like New System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificate.ValidationCallback(AddressOf CertValidation) work? Where cert validation is a function checking the issuer? Or even accepting all certificates, in the testing. Or is it a different issue altogether? Sorry for such basic questions, it's just that programming is not something I do on a daily basis and I can't find answers to my questions anywhere online.

Comment: Yes, Tls 1.0 is a default one (Ssl3 and Tls 1.0). About the callback, I propose this modification: `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
Function(obj As Object, cert As X509Certificate, chain As X509Chain, PolicyErrors As SslPolicyErrors) As Boolean If cert.Issuer.Equals("xxxxxx") Then Return True End If  Return False  End Function`. (Function(...) goes in a new line). Or `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf ServerValidationCallback` and create a new `ServerValidationCallback` method with the same parameters.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you, I've modified the callback according to your suggestion (#2), however the underlying issue as I described above is still there. Is there any other reason why it might not be working and certificate validation is not being called?

Comment: Try inserting this on top of your method: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`. Then, update you question with the code you have so far. -- When you run your code, put a breakpoint on the first line of your FtpRequest method, then proceed step by step. When the FtpWebResponse is initialized, you code must continue from the callback. See if this happens.